# is syringaldazine soluble in water?

Tags: solubility, solvents

Would it be better to use water or ethanol as a solvent for syringaldazine? Why? Would water interfere with the oxidation of syringaldazine if laccase enzyme was added?

Comment: I refer to a post, which refers to a paper:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_I_dissolve_Syringaldazine_SGZ_to_measure_laccase_activity

"The assay mixture contained 0.2 mM syringaldazine (dissolved in 60% ethanol) and 40 mM citrate-buffer, pH 5.6. Oxidation of syringaldazine was followed by an absorbance increase at 525 nm (ϵ525 = 65 000 dm3 M−1 cm−1) at a temperature of 25°C"

Ignoring what is stated in the link (which confirms the idea) I doubt that water would interfere, since the molecule is stable in water, and since the enzyme works in a environment in which water is present

Comment: The use of ethanol is necessary in order to dissolve the otherwise poorly soluble substrate (21.06 mg/L in water at 25°C)